# How to iterate the sub projects in maven pom?

Tags: maven, jacoco

I have multiple sub projects in maven:

```
-- main
     -- sub1
       -- sub1-1
       -- sub1-2

     -- sub2
       -- sub2-1
       -- sub2-2
```

for generating the reports, I have written a jacoco task like:

```
<executiondata>
    <fileset dir="path here">
        <include name="fileName" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="path here">
        <include name="fileName" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="path here">
        <include name="fileName" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="path here">
        <include name="fileName" />
    </fileset>
</executiondata>
```

here I'm manually adding the `dir` value to each project location. I knew the structure is going to be like `sub1/sub1-1/target`,`sub1/sub1-2/target` etc.

Is there any way in which I can iterate the subproject and solve the above manual issue?

Comment: Ah...adding the appropriate modules via `<module>..</module>`...

Comment: @khmarbaise: I didn't get